# There's a lone curly brace on the preferences tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

When you go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/me, a lone curly brace can be seen.

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Comment: This looks to be an issue across the network.

Comment: cross-site-dupe on SEmeta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328573/there-is-an-unwanted-close-curly-brace-in-the-preferences-page

Comment: Awwww it must feel so lonely!!

Comment: Somebody failed at shaving.  … This is a Razor joke, btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am happy to report that the offending `}` is gone.